# Close queue does not show all close votes

Tags: bug

In the close queue, I see questions that someone has flagged as a duplicate and others have flagged as off topic. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23159189/parsing-word-with-chars-and-ints-in-java) came up in the queue, and I saw this:
[image]

The question has been flagged as a duplicate, but it doesn't show up as such on the close queue dialog. Usually the close dialog shows how many votes were cast for each reason. I expect to see a "1" next to "duplicate of" on the main close dialog (in the empty circle). However, when I click "duplicate of", I see

[image]

Has anyone else noticed this?

Comment: Because it has been *flagged* as a duplicate, but no actual *close vote* on duplicate has been casted yet.

Comment: I thot blue round-rect number things *always* indicate votes. If not, then they need to be color coded better.

Comment: What is the difference between being flagged and being voted on?

Comment: Users with less than 3000 reputation can only flag questions for closure. These flags send the questions to the close review queue, where users with more than 3000 reputation can cast close votes which have the actual power to close a question. The flag is only meant to suggest an action for the people with the power to close, while the actual moderation is performed via close votes.

Comment: I personally don't really consider this a bug. It might be a useful feature to split votes and flags with 2 numbers in 2 different colours or something along those lines.